# JQuery Uncaught Type Error: modal.open is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a modal window by clicking on a link. However, the console is returning a `Uncaught TypeError: modal.open is not a function`. I checked to make sure that I put semi-colons everywhere required. Anyone with fresh eyes have any idea what I am missing?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/422wwt1e/1/)

### HTML

```
<a href="" id="nav-download">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

### JQUERY

```
var modal = (function(){
    var
    method = {},
    $overlay,
    $modal,
    $content;

    // Append the HTML
    $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    $content = $('<div id="content"></div>');

    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $modal.append($content);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append($overlay, $modal);
    });

    $('#overlay').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        method.close();
    });

    // Center the modal in the viewport
    method.center = function () {
        var top, left;

        top = Math.max($(window).height() - $modal.outerHeight(), 0) / 2;
        left = Math.max($(window).width() - $modal.outerWidth(), 0) / 2;

        $modal.css({
            top:top + $(window).scrollTop(),
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
        });
    };

    // Open the modal
    method.open = function (settings) {
        $content.empty().append(settings.content);

        $modal.css({
            width: settings.width || 'auto',
            height: settings.height || 'auto'
        });

        method.center();

        $(window).bind('resize.modal', method.center);

        $modal.show();
        $overlay.show();
    };

    // Close the modal
    method.close = function () {
        $modal.hide();
        $overlay.hide();
        $content.empty();
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    return method;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav-download').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.open({content: "<p>Get a link to download our free mobile app to your smart phone!</p>"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var modal = (function(){
    // ...
});
```

`modal` is a function.  It doesn't have an `open` property.

I assume you meant to *run* that function.  Try:

```
var modal = (function(){
    // ...
}());
// ^ Notice the `()` here
```

Answer (score 0):

`modal` is a function, not an object. You need to do:

```
var m = modal();
m.open(...);
```

Or use an IIFE to call the function immediately when you're assigning `modal`, as in Rocket Hazmat's answer.